# Autocomplete "," comma separated auto complete with cross button like gmail composer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to implement same functionality as gmail does while adding multiple email addresses separated by comma, but it has to be done in textbox (without dropdownlist)
Is there any example or suggestion?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Explain more about what you want.

Comment: You need select2 https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you've tried so far. Please post code to avoid people downvoting the post, SO is not intended for simply requesting others to do the coding for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me. I solved it using bootstrap-tagsinput.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.tagsinput/0.4.2/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
```

Then use it in html textbox-

```
<input type="text" name="cities" class="form-control"
               value="Hanoi" data-role="tagsinput" />
```

Please refer this 
 [link](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-tagsinput/) for more info.